# How to avoid prompting password with API AuthOozieClient - AuthType.KERBEROS

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, oozie

I have code as below to get the jobs status of current running Co-ordinators using OozieClient API from the different box which is not part of the cluster. Using AuthType as KERBEROS. When ever I am calling the object authClient (as below), to get the status of the co-ordinators, its prompting for the username and password again and again. **Can you please help me to how to avoid the username and password prompting.**
**Code**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.oozie.client.AuthOozieClient;
import org.apache.oozie.client.BulkResponse;
import org.apache.oozie.client.BundleJob;
import org.apache.oozie.client.CoordinatorJob;
import org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient;
import org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClientException;
import org.apache.oozie.client.WorkflowJob;
import org.apache.oozie.client.WorkflowJob.Status;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.net.URL;
public class OozieJobClient {
    public static AuthOozieClient authClient = null;
    public static String OOZIE_SERVER_URL = "http://XAXAXA.XAXAXA.com:11000/oozie";
    public static String nameNode = "hdfs://XAXAXA.XAXAX.XAXAXA.XAXAXA.com:8020";
    public static OozieClient wc;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {           
            URL oozieUrl = new URL(OOZIE_SERVER_URL);
            //OozieJobClient client = new OozieJobClient(OOZIE_SERVER_URL);
            authClient = new AuthOozieClient(oozieUrl.toString(), AuthOozieClient.AuthType.KERBEROS.toString());            
            Properties conf = authClient.createConfiguration();
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.set("fs.defaultFS", nameNode);
            config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
            config.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
            config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
            UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("myusername@XAXAXA.COM", 
  "C:\\ici_fw\\Hadoop\\myusername.keytab");

            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "XAXAXA.COM");
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "C:\\ici_fw\\krb5.ini");
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "axaxaxax.com");           
            System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
            System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\\ici_fw\\jaas.conf");         
            List<BundleJob> runningBundlesList = authClient.getBundleJobsInfo("user=jobsusername", 1, 4000);
            System.out.println(runningBundlesList);
            for (BundleJob obj1 : runningBundlesList) {
                System.out.println(obj1.getAppName() + ", " + obj1.getId() + ", " + obj1.getStatus() + ", "
                        + obj1.getCoordinators());

                System.out.println(authClient.getBundleJobInfo(obj1.getId()).getCoordinators());
                
            }
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (OozieClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   }}
```

**output:**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.6/slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.4.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
null
Kerberos username [MYUSERNAME]: myusername [PROMPT1]
Kerberos password for myusername: mypassword [PROMPT1]
Kerberos username [MYUSERNAME]: myusername [PROMPT2]
Kerberos password for myusername: mypassword [PROMPT2]
[Bundle id[0031119-201108094620631-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0013446-201108094923150-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0013436-201108094923150-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0029646-201108094620631-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0022880-201108094742175-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0022131-201108094620631-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0010296-201108094851999-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0004481-201108094923150-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0003595-201108094923150-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0033268-201011102512157-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0030233-201011102515944-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0025747-201011102515944-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0017968-201011102515944-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0019437-201011102512157-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0069111-200913110022211-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0057009-200913110022211-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0022712-200913110100677-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0010082-200913110022211-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0013891-200831170601093-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0013117-200831170600297-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0013110-200831170600297-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0007502-200831170606985-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], Bundle id[0007034-200831170606985-oozie-oozi-B] status[<STATUS>], ]
ICXXX_XXXXXXXX_CCLOAD, 0043335-210117205952974-oozie-oozi-B, <STATUS>, []
Kerberos username [myusername]: XXXXXXXXXXXXX.......so on
```

Comment: Your code connects to Oozie; **then** it tries to authenticate against the Kerberos KDC, with a keytab (containing an encrypted password); and **afterwards** you provide the Kerberos config including the address of the KDC. Seems logical that the Oozie connection has no Kerberos credentials available, and asks for user/password _(but anyway it has no valid Kerberos config so it will fail miserably)_.

Comment: In case it was not clear enough: Java is an imperative language. The order of instructions is important. You can't just stuff lines of code randomly and expect the compiler to sort out the mess for you.

Comment: Perhaps running your code with `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` to see more details will be helpful.

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter, Thanks for your solution less lecture, I was able to solve the problem with imperative language itself, compiler randomly sorted mess for me, chill.. ;)